# Calling OpenConnect VPN client in docker container shows TUNSETIFF failed: Operation not permitted

Tags: docker, vpn

I'm calling openconnect inside an ubuntu based docker container. It successfully connects to the server and prompt for my password, but then

```
Got CONNECT response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
CSTP connected. DPD 30, Keepalive 20
TUNSETIFF failed: Operation not permitted
```

I search for the TUNSETIFF word and every answer is about the command not running in sudo, but I am already root inside the container. What else can go wrong?

Comment: Try starting the container with `--privileged`.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

By default, Docker containers are started with a reduced set of linux capabilities (see `man capabilities`). The reduced set doesn't include some network related functionality (presumably so that containers can't sniff traffic from the host or other containers).

To start a container with full network capabilities, either explicitly add the `SYS_NET_ADMIN` capability with `--cap-add` argument e.g:

```
docker run -d --cap-add SYS_NET_ADMIN myimage
```

Or give the container the full set of privileges with `--privileged` e.g:

```
docker run -d --privileged myimage
```

Comment: unfortunately `SYS_NET_ADMIN` is not available in docker 17.xx, you could use `SYS_ADMIN` _to perform a range of system administration operations_ or `NET_ADMIN` _to perform various network-related operations_. Anyway **--cap-add NET_ADMIN** will do the deal with openconnect.

Comment: If you do not run the container privileged but only with `NET_ADMIN` capability added you need to pass the tunnel device via e.g.:

`docker run -d --cap-add NET_ADMIN --device /dev/net/tun myimage`

Comment: @karlsebal is this OS or version dependent? `NET_ADMIN` and device allow me to start a container. However, the connection did not work for me on *macOS 10.15.6* and *Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350* yielding `Cannot open "/proc/sys/net/ipv4/route/flush": Read-only file system`

Comment: `docker run --rm -it --network host --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --device=/dev/net/tun` still fails with `[Errno 1] Operation not permitted` for `fcntl.ioctl(self.tun, TUNSETIFF, ifr)`

Answer (score 3):

Either run the container privileged via

`docker run -d --privileged myimage`

as Adrian pointed out or run it with the `NET_ADMIN` capability added and pass the tunnel device e.g.:

`docker run -d --cap-add NET_ADMIN --device /dev/net/tun myimage`

Answer (score 0):

Starting the container with --privileged. (Thanks Adrian Mouat for the answer).

Comment: Glad it worked for you. I added a full answer below. I'm guessing --cap-add SYS_NET_ADMIN will also work.